# automake: use local headers instead of installed

Tags: mingw, automake

I recently migrated a few projects from vanilla make to automake. Although I am not the biggest fan of the GNU autotools, they solve many problems quite nicely. (No I do not want recommendations on other builds systems.)

The project layout is quite standard, I basically have one folder **include** that contains the public headers and one folder **src** that contains the sources and private headers. Since I am using C++ the sources need to include the public headers.

The basic solution is to use **AM_CXXFLAGS**, like so:

```
AM_CXXFLAGS = -Iinclude
```

But I am working allot on MinGW-W64 and MSys. To make the mingw behave like a POSIX environment, that is include from `/usr/include` and `/usr/local/include`, I define the variables `CPPFLAGS`, `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` appropriately.

*CPPFLAGS is not a mistake, it is for the preprocessor, configure needs this or it will complain.*

Now once the library is "installed" in the system and continue developing, I get the problem that the headers are pulled from `/usr/local/include` instead of the local folder. The problem is that the `AM_CXXFLAGS` gets appended to the `CXXFLAGS` and thus the local folder is later in the search order than the system folder.

With vanilla make the solution way easy, when extending `CXXFLAGS` you preceded the include directive, like so:

```
CXXFLAGS := -Iinclude $(CXXFLAGS) -g -Wall
```

This obviously also works with automake, except it needs to be `CPPFLAGS`, since libtool takes that into account. But automake rightfully complains that `CPPFLAGS` is being overwritten. Is there a correct way to do this, or do I need to live with the warning forever? *(Restructuring the project layout, being the only other solution.)*

Comment: What automake version? Here with 1.13.1 `AM_CPPFLAGS` (which is the one you should use for preprocessor flags such as -I) has precedence in the command line over CPPFLAGS. This is even [documented in the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Flag-Variables-Ordering.html). That page also shows how to define your own ordering (use `foo_CPPFLAGS = $(AM_CPPFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS)` for instance).

Comment: The version is 1.12.6... MinGW tends to lag behind. I will look into the issue. (When that change was introduced and/or upgrading automake.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write that you're using:

```
AM_CXXFLAGS = -Iinclude
```

This is incorrect; `-I` arguments should be placed in the `AM_CPPFLAGS` (C preprocessor) variable, because it is the preprocessor that evaluates `#include` macros.